Extract a value in another cell in excel
I am developing a gantt chart. I have refer to an end time of a task.
example below.

Now I want to refer to dependency A2, find its end time and that is start time of my task A3
I also want to put reference =A2 instead of a string.

If the start time of a new task is always the end time of the previous, just refer to that cell, so in C3 you'd put =D2, in D3 you'd put =C3+B3.  and in E3 put =ADRESS(ROW(A2),COLUMN(A2)) this will output A2 add ="="&ADRESS(ROW(A2),COLUMN(A2)) to output =A2.

Start time of a task can be end time of any other task. Only exception is first task

This solution doesnt solve my problem. I want a feature which looks at co ordinate of dependency and find its end time. Perhaps I need to model it in RDBMS where dependency is a relation table

Dependency is your own input? Together with task and duration I suppose?

Leave =A2 at cell E3.
In cell C3 put =INDIRECT("D"&ROW(INDIRECT(E3)))
In cell D3 put =C3+B3
For other cell, can just select & copy C3:D3 , then paste. The used reference will adjust accordingly.
Please share if it works/not/understandable.
